# pgfplots - close path for surrounding rectangle

Tags: pgfplots

is it possible to close the path from the coordinate frame in pgfplots? If I plot something, the frame rectangle of the coordinate system looks fine except the bottom left corner: the lines do not nicely consolidate (so the path looks "unclosed"). Is there a way to do so? This looks especially weird when you use a big line width.

I'll uploaded a screenshot [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19186705/Screenshot.png). As you might see, the top corner looks nice, the bottom don't.

**EDIT: Screenshot**

Now the direct screenshot directly here :)

[image]

As mentioned above: the top corner looks nice, the bottom don't.

Comment: Search for the `boxed` option in the manual for axis lines.

Comment: @percuße: I found \begin{axis}[axis lines=box]... but it won't compile correct.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Ok, the problem was an outdated version of pgfplots. But still, no change when I choose axis lines=box. Since it is the default value, it is no surprise to me.

Comment: A screenshot would probably help.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post an image :( I'll try to upload into dropbox and post the link in a few minutes.

Comment: you can include your image as an hyperlink and we can turn it into an image link while you get enough reputation.

Comment: Yeah, enough rep to upload an image! And here we go, added it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in PGFPlots. The axis is meant to be closed, but the conditional that checks whether there are axis discontinuities (in which case the axis line should not be closed) has its `\else` conditions mixed up (I think...)

You can fix the function by pasting the following chunk into your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\pgfplots@drawaxis@outerlines@cycledpath{%
    \draw[
        /pgfplots/every outer x axis line, % using these outer styles is only useful in conjunction with 'separate axis lines=true'
        /pgfplots/every outer y axis line]
    \pgfextra\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfplotsqpointxy{\pgfplots@xmin}{\pgfplots@ymin}}\endpgfextra
\ifpgfplots@hide@y
    { \pgfextra\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfplotsqpointxy{\pgfplots@xmin}{\pgfplots@ymax}}\endpgfextra }
\else
    decorate [ydiscont,decoration={pre length=\ydisstart, post length=\ydisend}]
    % { -- (\pgfplots@xmin, \pgfplots@ymax) }
    { \pgfextra\pgfpathlineto{\pgfplotsqpointxy{\pgfplots@xmin}{\pgfplots@ymax}}\endpgfextra }
\fi
\ifpgfplots@hide@x
    %{ (\pgfplots@xmax, \pgfplots@ymax) }
    { \pgfextra\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfplotsqpointxy{\pgfplots@xmax}{\pgfplots@ymax}}\endpgfextra }
\else
    decorate [xdiscont,decoration={pre length=\xdisstart, post length=\xdisend}] 
    %{ -- (\pgfplots@xmax,  \pgfplots@ymax) }
    { \pgfextra\pgfpathlineto{\pgfplotsqpointxy{\pgfplots@xmax}{\pgfplots@ymax}}\endpgfextra }
\fi
\ifpgfplots@hide@y
    %{ (\pgfplots@xmax, \pgfplots@ymin) }
    { \pgfextra\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfplotsqpointxy{\pgfplots@xmax}{\pgfplots@ymin}}\endpgfextra }
\else
    decorate [ydiscont,decoration={pre length=\ydisend, post length=\ydisstart}] 
    %{ -- (\pgfplots@xmax,  \pgfplots@ymin) }
    { \pgfextra\pgfpathlineto{\pgfplotsqpointxy{\pgfplots@xmax}{\pgfplots@ymin}}\endpgfextra }
\fi
\ifpgfplots@hide@x
    %{ (\pgfplots@xmin, \pgfplots@ymin) }
    { \pgfextra\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfplotsqpointxy{\pgfplots@xmin}{\pgfplots@ymin}}\endpgfextra }
\else
    decorate [xdiscont,decoration={pre length=\xdisend, post length=\xdisstart}] 
    %{ -- (\pgfplots@xmin,  \pgfplots@ymin) }
    { \pgfextra\pgfpathlineto{\pgfplotsqpointxy{\pgfplots@xmin}{\pgfplots@ymin}}\endpgfextra }
\fi
    % make sure that we do not have any of the axis discontinuities
    % here - they should not be closed.
    \if0\pgfplots@xaxisdiscontnum
        \if0\pgfplots@yaxisdiscontnum
            -- cycle
        \fi
    \fi
    ;%
}%
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I will try to give the developer a hint that there might be a bug.

Comment: @DaPhil: Glad it helps! I just filed a [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3602977&group_id=224188&atid=1060656)

Comment: Yeah and I just saw that :)

Comment: @DaPhil: ...and it has been fixed!